# Почему при добавлении в таблицу возникает ошибка?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<KekDB>());
            char a;
            string name, family;
            int age;
            using (KekDB db=new KekDB())
            {
                //try
                //{
                    Console.WriteLine("Input char");
                    a=Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("Input age");
                    age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("Input name");
                    name =Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("Input family");
                    family = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
                    var cl =new  ClassRoom(a);
                    db.ClassTable.Add(cl);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    var pr = new Person(name,family,age,cl);
                    db.PersonTable.Add(pr);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                //catch (Exception)
                //{

                //    Console.WriteLine("Error");
                //}
           // }
            Console.WriteLine("Input smt");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
 public class ClassRoom
    {
        [Key]
        public char letter { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Person> persons { get; set; }
        public ClassRoom() { }
        public ClassRoom(char a)
        {
            letter = a;
            persons = new List<Person>();
        }
    }
 public class Person
    {
        public int personId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName{get;set;}
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public ClassRoom clas { get; set; }
        public Person() { }
         public Person(string firstName,string lastName,int Age,ClassRoom cl)
        {
            FirstName = firstName;
            LastName = lastName;
            this.Age = Age;
            clas = cl;
        }
    }
```

Необработанное исключение: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: При установлении соединения с SQL Ser
ver произошла ошибка, связанная с сетью или с определенным экземпляром. Сервер не найден или недосту
пен. Убедитесь, что имя экземпляра указано правильно и что на SQL Server разрешены удаленные соедине
ния. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Произошла ошибка Local Database Runtime.Невозмож
но создать автоматический экземпляр. Дополнительные сведения об ошибке см. в журнале событий приложе
ний Windows.
)
   в System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConn
ectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, S
ecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOpt
ions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTran
sientFaultHandling)
   в System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConn
ectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConne
ction, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   в System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbCo
nnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions
 userOptions)
   в System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionO
ptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   в System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnec
tionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   в System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 wa
itForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOption
s userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   в System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompl
etionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   в System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, Ta
skCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbC
onnectionInternal& connection)
   в System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConne
ction, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions user
Options)
   в System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbC
onnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   в System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   в System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   в System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   в System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.b__36(DbConnection
t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext c)
   в System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TIntercept
ionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 e
xecuting, Action`3 executed)
   в System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connect
ion, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   в System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.<>c__DisplayClass33.b__32()
   в System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0()
   в System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   в System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)
   в System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Ac
tion`1 act)
   в System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection sqlConnecti
on, Action`1 act)
   в System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.CreateDatabaseFromScript(Nullable`1 commandTim
eout, DbConnection sqlConnection, String createDatabaseScript)
   в System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Null
able`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nulla
ble`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateDatabase()
   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DatabaseCreator.Create(DbConnection connection)
   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)

в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(InternalContext internalContext, Fun
c`3 createMigrator, ObjectContext objectContext)
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CreateDatabase(ObjectContext objectContext, Databas
eExistenceState existenceState)
   в System.Data.Entity.Database.Create(DatabaseExistenceState existenceState)
   в System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseAlways`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.<CreateInitializationAction>b_
_e()
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext c)
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action)
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase()
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.AddRange(IEnumerable entities)
   в System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 entities)
   в _002_1_to_M.Program.Main(String[] args) в D:\Видео\entity framework\Entity Framework 6\002_Fund
amentals EF_6\003_Relations\002_1_to_M\Program.cs:строка 23
Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .

Comment: Сообщения об ошибках лучше включить в виде текста.

Comment: Как это сделать?

Comment: Нажать правой кнопкой в окне консоли. В выпадающем меню выбрать пункт «Выделить все» («Select All»). Нажать Enter после чего весь вывод вставить в текст вопроса (правится по ссылке «править» под текстом вопроса).

Comment: В сообщении говорится о том, что провайдер не смог достучаться до экземпляра SQL Server. Проверьте строку подключения.

Comment: а что здесь мб не так?(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB

Comment: @Nikita, честно говоря, очень много чего. Скажите, какой подход Вы используете, Code First, Model First или DB First? Если последний, то уточните, где у Вас находится сама БД?

Comment: @Serafim Prozorov  Code First

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка очевидна: "Сервер не найден или недоступен.". Вам необходимо проверить строку соединения след.образом.

1) Нам нужно отрыть окно `SQL Server Object Explorer`

[image: меню открытия окна]

2) Найти наш сервер и прав.кликом выбрать пункт свойства

[image: выбор пункта меню]

3) В окне свойств найти раздел `Connection string` выделить значение этой

[image: раздел строки соединения с сервером]

строки и скопировать и вставить в нужное место вашей программы.